# Question about conditional probability when condition involves more than one event

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose $A, B, C$ are events.
I seem to not be understanding correctly the concepts of conditional probability when it is conditioned on more than one events. Specifically, how does one express
$P(A|B \cup C)$ and $P(A|B \cap C)$ in terms of more simpler (conditioned only on $B$ or $C$) conditional probabilities?

Comment: $B\cup C$ is one event, as is $B\cap C$.  You may *describe* it using multiple events, but that's just how you describe it.  Say you are tossing a fair die and let $B$ be the event "the die comes up odd" and let $C$ be the event "the die comes up prime".  Then $B=\{1,3,5\}$, $C=\{2,3,5\}$, $B\cup C=\{1,2,3,5\}$ and $B\cap C=\{3,5\}$.  Breaking the union and the intersection down further does, of course, depend on information about the defining events.

Comment: Good to know in this context:  $P(A\mid B\cap C)$ and $P(A\mid B,C)$ denote the same conditional probability.

Comment: Right, let me reword my question